# 400 bad request while submitting form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, react-router-dom

i am getting an error like 400 bad request while submitting form don't know whats going on wrong please help to solve my error

This img will help you to catch error
https://ibb.co/X8NKGzd and  https://ibb.co/Y8fXsBj

> addMovie.js

This is my frontend addmovie logic

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Navbar from '../pages/Navbar';
import Footer from '../pages/Footer';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {isAuthenticated} from '../Auth/index';
import {addMovie} from '../Admin/adminapicall';

const AddMovie = () => {

  const {user,token} = isAuthenticated();

const [values,setValues] = useState({
    movie_name:'',
    actor:'',
    country_of_origin:'',
    duration:'',
    director:'',
    photo:'',
    loading:false,
    error:'',
    addedMovie:'',
    getRedirect:false,
    // formData:''
})

    const {movie_name,actor,country_of_origin,duration,director,photo,loading,error,addedMovie,getRedirect} = values;

    const handleChange = name => event => {
        const value = name === "photo" ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value
        // formData.set(name,value); 
        setValues({...values,[name]:value})
    };

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setValues({...values,error:'',loading:true})
        addMovie(user._id,token,JSON.stringify(values)).then(data =>{
          if(data.error){
            setValues({...values,error:data.error})
          }else{
            setValues({
              ...values,
              movie_name:'',
              actor:'',
              country_of_origin:'',
              duration:'',
              director:'',
              photo:'',
              loading:false,
              addedMovie: data.movie_name
            })
          }
        })
        
    }

    const successMessage = () => (
      <div className='alert alert-success mt-3'
         style={{display : addedMovie ? '' : 'none'}}>
           <h4>{addedMovie} added successfully</h4>
        </div>
    )


    // const successMessage = () => {
      
    // }

    const addMovieForm = () => (
        <form >
          <span>Post photo</span>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="btn btn-block btn-success">
              <input
                onChange={handleChange("photo")}
                type="file"
                name="photo"
                accept="image"
                placeholder="choose a file"
              />
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              onChange={handleChange("movie_name")}
              name="photo"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="movie_name"
              value={movie_name}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              onChange={handleChange("actor")}
              name="photo"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="actor"
              value={actor}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              onChange={handleChange("duration")}
              type="number"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="duration"
              value={duration}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              onChange={handleChange("country_of_origin")}
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="country_of_origin"
              value={country_of_origin}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <input
              onChange={handleChange("director")}
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              placeholder="director"
              value={director}
            />
          </div>
          
          <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-success mb-2">
            Add Movie
          </button>
        </form>
      );
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
                <div className='container'style={{height:'0px'}}>
              <Link to='/admin/dashboard'> <h1 className=' bg-info text-white p-4 text-decoration-none'>Admin Home</h1> </Link>
              <div className='row bg-dark text-white rounded'>
                    <div className='col-md-8 offset-md-2'>
                      {successMessage()}
                      {addMovieForm()}
                    </div>

                </div> 

                </div>
                
            <Footer/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddMovie;
```

> api call

This is my api request where frontend is talk with backend

```
import {API} from '../backend';

//add movie
export const addMovie = (userId,token,movie)=>{
    return fetch(`${API}/movie/addMovie/${userId}`,{
        method : "POST",
        headers:{
            Accept:'Application/json',
            "Content-Type" : "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body:JSON.stringify(movie)
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

//get all movie

export const getAllMovies = () => {
    return fetch(`${API}/movies`,{
        method : "GET"
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

//get a movie

export const getMovie = movieId =>{
    return fetch(`${API}/movie/${movieId}`,{
        method : "GET"
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

//update movie

export const updateMovie = (movieId,userId,token,movie)=>{
    return fetch(`${API}/movie/${movieId}/${userId}`,{
        method : "PUT",
        headers:{
            Accept:'Application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        },
        body:movie
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

//delete movie

export const deleteMovie = (movieId,userId,token)=>{
    return fetch(`${API}/movie/${movieId}/${userId}`,{
        method : "DELETE",
        headers:{
            Accept:'Application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

##backend##

> addmovie.js

This is backend addmovie logic where error occure

```
exports.addMovie = (req, res) => {
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm(); // declare a form
    form.keepExtensions = true;

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, file) => {   //parse the form like err,fields,file
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Problem with image"
            });
        }

        //destructure the field
        const {movie_name,actor,country_of_origin,duration,director } = fields;
        if (!movie_name || !actor || !country_of_origin || !duration || !director) 
        {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "please include all fields"
            })
        }

        let movie = new Movie(fields);

        //handle file here
        if (file.photo) {
            if (file.photo.size > 300000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "file size to big!"
                })
            }
            movie.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(file.photo.path)
            movie.photo.contentType = file.photo.type;

        }

        //save to the database
        movie.save((err, movie) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400).json({
                    error: "saving movie in database failed"
                })
            }
            res.json(movie);
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: what is the error your getting inside `form.parse`, can you also add output of `console.log(err)`

Comment: ok check console error https://ibb.co/Y8fXsBj

Comment: Just set headers for every request. 
`headers:{
    Accept:'Application/json'
}`

Comment: @user13427179, set content-type header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Comment: when i add Content-Type' : 'application/json' then then getting new error  https://ibb.co/9214R1m